# How to implement fragments inside tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment

What i require is two tabs(fixed) in the main activity. Inside each tab i need four fragment to be loaded on pressing next button from first to second and second to third and so on. Is this possible if yes how should i implement it? I am using minsdk as 8 with a support libraries.

currently i am using viewpager for my main activity. and it has code as follows

---

```
public class RegisterMainPage extends ActionBarActivity{

private ViewPager viewPager = null;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_main_page);
    //setting up an action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public static final int PAGE_NUMS = 2;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(arg0 == 0){
            fragment = new RegistrationIndividual();
        }
        if(arg0 == 1){
            fragment = new RegistrationOrganizational();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGE_NUMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(position == 0){
            return "Individual Member";
        }
        if(position == 1){
            return "Organizational Member";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

---

and in its xml i have

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="htto://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:content=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#16BDFF"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: Four fragments in each tab?!

Comment: what i am trying to do is sort of like registration page. User is to be able to fill 4 page description under two different field(tabs).

Comment: I think what i want to do is little bit not clear from above explanation. I want to load one fragment after another in a single tab on pressing a button not all of them at once. i think it would solve itself if i can find how to load fragments dynamically in a tab